# The even places in my array automatically turn into 0. Can you fix my code?

Tags: c

I have written this program which requires you to input values of elements in a 1D array from element number 1, it will stop when you input the value of 0.

```
void main() {
    int *A;
    int n, j, B;
    int i = 1;

    A = malloc(i * sizeof(int));
    printf("Enter the element A[%d] = ", i);
    scanf("%d",&A[i]);
    while (i>=1) {
        if (A[i] != 0) {
            i = i + 1;
            A = realloc(A, i * sizeof(int));
            printf("Enter the element A[%d] = ",i);
            scanf("%d",&A[i]);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    for (j = 1 ; j <= i; j++) {
        printf("\t%d", A[j]);
    }

    for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        free(A[j]);
    }
}
```

Here's the result: [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9V9PZ.png), [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDEiR.png).

As you can see, even places are replaced with 0. I cant figure out why and how to fix this.

Comment: `int i=1;
  A=malloc(i*sizeof(int));[...]
  scanf("%d",&A[i]);` Out-of-bounds access, undefined behavior.

Comment: and the `free` loop is wrong. There's only `free(A)` to perform. Not to mention the print loop which should start at 0 and stop at i-1

Comment: @EOF thank you I can fix it now

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  it is missing the needed `#include` statements.  Do you expect us to guess as to which header files your code actually uses?

Comment: there are only 2 valid signatures for the `main()` function.  Both of those signatures have a return type of `int`.  Suggest using the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling any of the heap memory allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc)  1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) when calling `realloc()`, always save the returned value into a temporary variable and check that variable for !=NULL and if not NULL, then assign to the target variable.  Otherwise, when `realloc()` fails the original heap memory pointer is overlayed, resulting in a memory leak.

Comment: this statement: `while (i>=1)` has absolutely no effect (unless more than 2gig entries are typed by the user.  Suggest replacing with: `int temp; while( 1 == scanf( "%d", &temp ) ) {  tempRealloc = realloc( A, (i+1) * sizeof(int) ); if( !tempRealloc() ) { handle error } else { A[i] = temp; i++; } if( !temp ) break;`  Note: a lot of the other code can then be eliminated

Comment: Note: in C, array indexes start with 0 and continue to (length of array -1)  so the posted code has some logic errors regarding where in the array the new value is placed.  infact new values are being placed 1 beyond the end of the array.  This results in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: when reaching this loop: `for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        free(A[j]);
    }` there is really only one allocation for the array, so that loop needs to be replaced with `free[A];`  Calling `free()` with the contents of the elements in the array `A[]` is undefined behavior as those contents are from the user, not from calls to malloc or realloc.  This can/will result in a seg fault event.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code

1. cleanly compiles
2. corrects all the problems listed in the comments to the OPs question
3. performs the desired functionality

and now the code

```
#include <stdio.h>   // scanf(), printf(), perror()
#include <stdlib.h>  // realloc(), exit(), EXIT_FAILURE


int main( void )
{
    int *A = NULL;
    int temp;
    size_t i = 0;

    printf("Enter the element A[%lu] = ", i+1);
    while( 1 == scanf("%d",&temp) )
    {
        int* tempRealloc = realloc(A, (i+1) * sizeof(int));
        if( !tempRealloc )
        {
            perror( "realloc failed" );
            free( A ); // cleanup
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, realloc successful

        A = tempRealloc;

        A[i] = temp;
        i++;

        if( !temp )  // 0 entered by user
            break;

        printf("Enter the element A[%lu] = ",i+1);
    }

    for (size_t j = 0 ; j < i; j++)
    {
        printf("\t%d", A[j]);
    }

    free( A );
} // end function: main
```

Comment: Note: if you really want to NOT use element 0 of the array, just modify the 'i' variable accordingly.  However, in general, the `A[0]` should be used just like any other element of the array